# Can someone explain how to append an element to an array in C programming?

Tags: c, arrays, integer, append

If I want to append a number to an array initialized to int, how can I do that?

```
int arr[10] = {0, 5, 3, 64};
arr[] += 5; //Is this it?, it's not working for me...
```

I want {0,5, 3, 64, 5} in the end.

I'm used to Python, and in Python there is a function called list.append that appends an element to the list automatically for you. Does such function exist in C?

Comment: array size should be initialized to contain this extra element

Comment: if you have enough memory you can append like this `arr[4] = 5` simply

Comment: A list and an array are very different types of containers. An array is a contiguous block of memory and if you want to append an element, you have to write it to the position following the last occupied position, provided the array is large enough.

Comment: Do you intend to use an array which grows when you append additional elements? In C++, you could use `std::vector` but C doesn't offer anything like it. You would have to manually allocate additional memory.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
int arr[10] = {0, 5, 3, 64};
arr[4] = 5;
```

**EDIT:**
So I was asked to explain what's happening when you do:

```
int arr[10] = {0, 5, 3, 64};
```

you create an array with 10 elements and you allocate values for the first 4 elements of the array.

Also keep in mind that  `arr` starts at index `arr[0]` and ends at index `arr[9]` - 10 elements

```
arr[0] has value 0;
arr[1] has value 5;
arr[2] has value 3;
arr[3] has value 64;
```

after that the array contains garbage values / zeroes because you didn't allocated any other values

But you could still allocate 6 more values so when you do

```
arr[4] = 5;
```

you allocate the value 5 to the fifth element of the array.

You could do this until you allocate values for the last index of the `arr` that is `arr[9]`;

Sorry if my explanation is choppy, but I have never been good at explaining things.

Comment: Please edit your question to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many posters on SO are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Comment: This isn't the type of appending OP was referring to. Appending is to add to the end of the array without using its index.

Comment: This answer is selected as correct but it's not correct actually. Or is this question was edited after a while so that answer looks like inappropriate?

Comment: Could you use arr[sizeof(arr)+1] = 5;

Answer (score 5):

There are only two ways to put a value into an array, and one is just syntactic sugar for the other:

```
a[i] = v;
*(a+i) = v;
```

Thus, to put something as the element at index 4, you don't have any choice but `arr[4] = 5`.

Comment: The array appears to be declared as `int arr[10]` which provides plenty of room.

Comment: @GregHewgill: I'm blind, apparently. Thanks.

Comment: The 4th element would be at `arr[3]` no?

Comment: @Musa: I count from 0th :)

Comment: While I understand what you mean by '4th' in terms of 0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th -- the wording *is* a bit misleading...

Answer (score 2):

You can have a counter (freePosition), which will track the next free place in an array of size n.

Comment: After this you can do. if(freePosition<n) 
arr[freePosition]= x;  /* here x is the element to be added at the end of array */

Answer (score 2):

For some people which might still see this question, there is another way on how to append another array element(s) in C. You can refer to [this](https://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-insert-element-in-array) blog which shows a C code on how to append another element in your `array`.

But you can also use `memcpy()` function, to append element(s) of another array. You can use `memcpy()`like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

int first_array[10] = {45, 2, 48, 3, 6};
int scnd_array[] = {8, 14, 69, 23, 5};
int i;

// 5 is the number of the elements which are going to be appended
memcpy(first_array + 5, scnd_array, 5 * sizeof(int));

// loop through and print all the array
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
  }

}
```

Comment: Why have you named the arrays `first_array` and `scnd_array` but then used `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a code like
`int arr[10] = {0, 5, 3, 64};` , and you want to append or add a value to next index, you can simply add it by typing `a[5] = 5`.

The main advantage of doing it like this is you can add or append a value to an any index not required to be continued one, like if I want to append the value `8` to index 9, I can do it by the above concept prior to filling up before indices.
But in python by using `list.append()` you can do it by continued indices.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer is:** You don't have any choice other than:

```
arr[4] = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Append(int arr[],int n,int ele){
    int size = n+1; // increasing the size
    int arrnew[size]; // Creating the new array:

    for(int i = 0; i<size;i++){
        arrnew[i] = arr[i]; // copy the element old array to new array:

    }
    arrnew[n] = ele; // Appending the element:
}


by above simple method you can append the value
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong as you allocate a temporary array int arrnew[size] within your function and set an extra value in this array. When the function exits, the arrnew is not valid anymore. Please read other answer for a valid answer and read about scope variables, heap and stack allocation (malloc etc..), this will help you understand better memory management

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method that always works, then store the initial size of the array in an `int size = 0;` variable and increase it every time you append a new element: **`array[size++] = ...`**

```c
int array[5];
int size = 0; // you can set the size variable larger 
              // if there are already elements in the array

array[size++] = 12;   // append 1. element
array[size++] = 23;   // append 2. element
array[size++] = 34;   // append 3. element
                      // ...
```