# Append function for C with dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, append, dynamic-memory-allocation

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26208788/4999991), I'm trying to modify the code provided in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@imjacobclark/working-with-dynamic-arrays-in-c-c7d40a3cea01) to create an `append` function using dynamic memory allocation. This is what I have so far:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct intlist_ {
  int size;
  int* list;
} intlist;

void append(intlist* arr, int value){
  realloc((*arr).list, sizeof((*arr).list) + sizeof(int));
  (*arr).size = (*arr).size + 1;
  (*arr).list[(*arr).size -1] = value;
}

int main() {

  intlist arr;
  arr.size = 4;
  arr.list = malloc(arr.size * sizeof(int));

  arr.list[0] = 0;
  arr.list[1] = 5;
  arr.list[2] = 3;
  arr.list[3] = 64;

  append(&arr, 12);

  for (int ii = 0; ii < arr.size; ii++)
    printf("%d, ", arr.list[ii]);

  free(arr.list);
  return 0;
}
```

However the result I get is wrong:

> clang version 7.0.0-3~ubuntu0.18.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_700/final)
>   main.c:10:3: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with
>   'warn_unused_result' attribute [-Wunused-result]
>                              realloc((*arr).list, sizeof((*arr).list) + sizeof(int));
>                                                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>                                                 1 warning generated.
>                                                                     0, 5, 3, 64, 0, 5, 3, 64, 12,

I'm using [this online compiler](https://repl.it/repls/IntelligentLightgreyArgument) for testing where you can also see the latest versions of the above code. I would appreciate if you could help me know where is my mistake and how I can solve it. Thanks for your support in advance.

**P.S.** You may a final version of the code here in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/22131bbc8771f5267b7987e1467af973).

Comment: Why do you think the result is wrong? I tried to compile it and I get correct result.

Comment: @EmirG. you are right. I have made horrible mistake in my original post forgetting to comment the first for loop out. :( shame. However The warning I'm getting is still an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Wrong size allocated.  `sizeof((*arr).list)` is the size of a pointer, not `int`.
- Return value not used.  `realloc()` returns the new pointer.
- No `NULL` check

Rather than use the error prone `ptr = some_alloc(sizeof(type) * n)`, use
`ptr = some_alloc(sizeof *ptr * n)`

---

```
void append(intlist *arr, int value){
  int *new_ptr = realloc(arr->list, sizeof *(arr->list) * (arr->size + 1u));
  if (new_ptr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  arr->list = new_ptr;
  arr->list[arr->size] = value;
  arr->size++;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I do not understand the `*(arr->list)` and `1u`. I also think the line `arr->list[arr->size] = value;` should be `arr->list[arr->size - 1] = value;` shouldn't it?

Comment: @Foad  `sizeof *(arr->list)` is the size of what `arr->list` points to.  With `int* list;`, the type pointer to in a `int`.

Comment: BTW the `new_arr == NULL` should change to `new_ptr == NULL`

Comment: @Foad Allocations take a `size_t` argument, some unsigned type.  `arr->size + 1u` adds 1, using `unsigned` math rather than `int math` in forming the size product.

Comment: @Foad "I also think the line arr->list[arr->size] = value; should be arr->list[arr->size - 1] = value; shouldn't it?".  No.  In effect you want `arr.list[4] = 12;`  This code does the assignment before incrementing `.size`.

Comment: Thanks for your kind support. you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Close, but:

1. `sizeof((*arr).list)` wont give you the size of the array. Instead it will give you the size of a `int*`.
2. `realloc` invalidates the original pointer, and continuing to use it is undefined behaviour. Use the returned value instead.

So change your realloc line to use the stored list size instead, and update the pointer with the return value:

```
(*arr).list = realloc((*arr).list, ((*arr).size + 1) * sizeof(int));
```

Couple of other tips:

- `ptr->` is the same as `(*ptr).` but easier to read. I suggest changing all your `(*arr).size` and `(*arr).list` to `arr->size` and `arr->list`.
- `realloc`, like its brethren, is not guaranteed to succeed. You should check the return value for `null` to catch errors.
- The clang warning is (as often is the case) helpful - checking the return value would have solved a couple of issues.

Comment: thanks. it seems the [original post](https://medium.com/@imjacobclark/working-with-dynamic-arrays-in-c-c7d40a3cea01) is also wrong then. However your solution did not remove the warning. 

Comment: `realloc((*arr).list, ((*arr).size + 1) * sizeof(int));` --> Nope. the reallocated value is discarded.  Only by UB are things still working.

Comment: @chux would you be kind to elaborate? It seems it is working fine.

Comment: @Foad Many reallocations do not use a new memory area, your code so far relies on that.  Keep calling your/this `append()` and code will fail.